# Arrange ggplot with three elements

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to arrange the bar ggplot according to sp level (sp1, sp2, sp3) and annotate the grouped bar plot with the sp name to which they belong.
Note, uddestion also welcome to better present the grouped bar graph of (Genotype and Treatment) and also distinghuish the bars to present species. I dont want to make facet or wrap graph. I need to build a grouped bargraph which rshos all these three elements.

[image]

Here is the dataset

| Genotype | Replication | Treatment | Specie | var |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| G1 | R1 | CT | Sp1 | 4.8100 |
| G1 | R2 | CT | Sp1 | 9.0400 |
| G2 | R1 | CT | Sp2 | 11.5000 |
| G2 | R2 | CT | Sp2 | 11.9368 |
| G3 | R1 | CT | Sp3 | 6.1400 |
| G3 | R2 | CT | Sp3 | 10.0750 |
| G4 | R1 | CT | Sp1 | 12.9000 |
| G4 | R2 | CT | Sp1 | 15.5830 |
| G5 | R1 | CT | Sp2 | 7.5200 |
| G5 | R2 | CT | Sp2 | 5.8600 |
| G6 | R1 | CT | Sp3 | 5.8100 |
| G6 | R2 | CT | Sp3 | 6.4835 |
| G1 | R1 | HS | Sp1 | 8.8200 |
| G1 | R2 | HS | Sp1 | 8.5700 |
| G2 | R1 | HS | Sp2 | 14.0000 |
| G2 | R2 | HS | Sp2 | 9.0084 |
| G3 | R1 | HS | Sp3 | 8.0650 |
| G3 | R2 | HS | Sp3 | 10.6000 |
| G4 | R1 | HS | Sp1 | 14.2000 |
| G4 | R2 | HS | Sp1 | 15.9015 |
| G5 | R1 | HS | Sp2 | 10.8000 |
| G5 | R2 | HS | Sp2 | 10.5000 |
| G6 | R1 | HS | Sp3 | 9.3600 |
| G6 | R2 | HS | Sp3 | 10.0766 |

and I am using this code

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=Genotype, y=var, fill=Treatment)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge(), color="black")+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1, colour = "black", face = "bold"))+
  geom_text(aes(label=Specie), position = position_dodge(width = 0.9), col='blue', angle=90)
```

Comment: Some of your Species / Genotype / Treatment combos have more than one replicate. Should these be averaged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what you don't like about your current plot, but you could use `geom_col_pattern` to help visually separate out the different variables:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggpattern)

df %>%
  group_by(Genotype, Treatment, Specie) %>%
  summarize(var = mean(var), .groups = 'drop') %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Genotype, y = var, fill = Specie)) +
  geom_col_pattern(aes(pattern = Treatment), pattern_color = '#00000050',
                   position = position_dodge(0.7), width = 0.5, 
                   color = 'gray50',
                   pattern_angle = 45, pattern_spacing = 0.02) +
  scale_pattern_manual(values = c('none', 'stripe'),
                       guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill = 'white'))
                       ) +
  scale_fill_brewer('Species', palette = 'Pastel2', 
                    guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(pattern = 'none'))
                    ) + 
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16) +
  theme(axis.text.x.bottom = element_text(face = "bold"),
        panel.spacing.x = unit(0, 'mm'),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_blank())
```

[image]